# Ruby operators and or; == eqls?

Tags: ruby, operators

1. what is the usage of and; or in ruby;  what is the reason that  `1` and `3` gives `3` but

   `x = 1
   y = 2
   x < 2 and y > 2
   => true`
2. what is the difference between `.eql?` and `==`
   Is there any difference when I code
   `sex=="M"` and `sex.eql?("M")`

Comment: `1 and 3` will give 3. is it a typo or you are really getting `2` instead of `3`?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I think you left out the formatting when you copied your homework question. Presumably part one is talking about the `and` and `or` operators so maybe you should go back and look at a Ruby operator precedence table.